# How to map mouse button to keyboard keys using xmodmap and xev

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, xmodmap

I use xmodmap and xev to bind my keyboard key to mouse button but when i try to map my mouse button to keyboard key it doesn't work, I can't get the mouse "*code*" using xev. Does xmodmap only work for keyboard to mouse? I would like to map my mouse button to keyboard key because i found it hard to type, when map <kbd>V</kbd> to right click(keyboard to mouse). My right click keys actually mapped on side button.